# Create folder in a relative path outside the project

Tags: java, spring, file, resources

How can i save a file to a relative path outside my project ? So i can create a folder of resources on any computer the program runs on?

I tried:

```
String folderPath=getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(".").getPath()+other stuff
```

to create a folder path where i save images. It creates a me a folder like tomcat%20v7.0 where indeed my images are saved. I keep absolute path for every picture in my database and then load them in a jsp file. When running the app in eclipse, everything works fine. When trying to run in browser, photos aren't shown.
Browser are installed on C: and tomcat/eclipse on E:

Comment: first of all you need to know that server works on HTTP protocal , i will not read your c:/ yourfile path.... you need to save file in tomcat or your servers webapp folder ........

Comment: and how can I get the path of my server webapp ?

Comment: is their any problem in my posted answer

Answer (score -1):

```
    public static List<String> getEndPoints() throws         
              MalformedObjectNameException,
            NullPointerException, UnknownHostException,
            AttributeNotFoundException, InstanceNotFoundException,
            MBeanException, ReflectionException {


        MBeanServer mbs = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();
        Set<ObjectName> objs = mbs.queryNames(new ObjectName(
                "*:type=Connector,*"), Query.match(Query.attr("protocol"),
                Query.value("HTTP/1.1")));

        String hostname = InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName();
        InetAddress[] addresses = InetAddress.getAllByName(hostname);
        ArrayList<String> endPoints = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (Iterator<ObjectName> i = objs.iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
            ObjectName obj = i.next();
            String scheme = mbs.getAttribute(obj, "scheme").toString();
            String port = obj.getKeyProperty("port");
            for (InetAddress addr : addresses) {
                String host = addr.getHostAddress();
                String ep = scheme + "://" + host + ":" + port;
                endPoints.add(ep);
            }
        }
        return endPoints;
    }

//use above code to get path like "http://yourip:yourport/yourwebapppath"
```